# Using .write function with multiple arguments for writing to a txt file - Python

Tags: python

I am trying to write the following loop to a .txt file (in addition to printing the output to terminal). On doing so I get an error that says:

```
> TypeError:function takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

I understand what the error is trying to convey, but is there a way to work around this. I do need the labels and the results output to the .txt file just like they are printed on the terminal

Here is the code I am using:

```
out_write = open(write_to, 'wb')

for arr in top_k:
    print(labels[arr], results[arr])
    out_write.write(labels[arr], results[arr])
print ("\n\n\n")
out_write("\n\n\n")
out_write.close()
```

I am working in python 2.7

Comment: `out_write.write('{} {}'.format(labels[arr], results[arr]))`

Comment: Make a single string (however you like to do that: concatenation, `%`, `.format()`, f-strings) or use two calls to `.write()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python offers many solutions to this problem. You can combine your arguments to make a single string using several methods:

- Convert to string and concatenate
  `out_write.write(str(labels[arr]) + " " + str(results[arr]) + "\n")`
- Old-school string interpolation using `%`
  `out_write.write("%s %s\n" % (labels[arr], results[arr]))`
- `str.format()`
  `out_write.write("{} {}\n".format(labels[arr], results[arr]))`
- f-strings, the new hotness
  `out_write.write(f"{labels[arr]} {results[arr]}\n")`

Or you can use `print()` itself:

```
print(labels[arr], results[arr], file=out_write)
```

To avoid the need to specify the `file` parameter in every call to `print()`, you can use `functools.partial`:

```
file_out = functools.partial(print, file=out_write)
file_out(labels[arr], results[arr])
```

Or a lambda!

```
file_out = lambda *args: print(*args, file=out_write)
file_out(labels[arr], results[arr])
```

Why not write a function that prints *and* writes at the same time? One call does it all!

```
out = lambda *args: print(*args) and print(*args, file=out_write)
```

Comment: Thank you! I took your str.format() advice, but it outputs the text onto the same line. Im sure I'm missing something very basic to go into a new line after it prints a "label result" combo. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, forgot to put newlines into the format strings. I just edited my answer to add those..

Comment: Perfect! That did it. Just one more thing, I am running this loop over multiple files, so essentially this for loop gets run multiple times but I think my code only prints the outputs to the for loop once (on the text file), the terminal has as many for loops as there are files in my dir since I am looping over them. What would a reason for this not being reflected in the out.txt? Thanks :)

Comment: I'd ask a new question for that.

Comment: Figured it out, its essentially just out_write = open(write_to, 'a') instead of the 'wb'!